# What is CC_Time in cocos2dx?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I was following this tutorial to understand using custom shaders : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Realistic_looking_animated_real-time_clouds

I understand that CC_Time is Cocos2d-x built-in uniform vec4-object that holds different versions of time in it's components. 
Can someone please explain or point me to a resource so that I can understand what are its different components. Thanks.

Comment: if you wanna read more on cocos2dx custom shaders here is a good post: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/advanced_topics/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file CCGLProgram.cpp located in cocos2d\cocos\renderer provides the answer:

```
  // This doesn't give the most accurate global time value.
        // Cocos2D doesn't store a high precision time value, so this will have to do.
        // Getting Mach time per frame per shader using time could be extremely expensive.
        float time = _director->getTotalFrames() * _director->getAnimationInterval();

        setUniformLocationWith4f(_builtInUniforms[GLProgram::UNIFORM_TIME], time/10.0, time, time*2, time*4);
        setUniformLocationWith4f(_builtInUniforms[GLProgram::UNIFORM_SIN_TIME], time/8.0, time/4.0, time/2.0, sinf(time));
        setUniformLocationWith4f(_builtInUniforms[GLProgram::UNIFORM_COS_TIME], time/8.0, time/4.0, time/2.0, cosf(time));
```